# SP2013 CSOM : Create a folder in sharepoint list 2013

Tags: 2013, csom

I am using below code to create a folder in sharepoint custom list but the folders are created with name "No Title".WHere is the code going wrong or i miss any attributes ?

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/91b369/create-a-folder-in-sharepoint-2013-using-javascript-jsom/

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this line between line before `this.oListItem.update()` statement (between lines 15 and 16 in the sample):

```
this.oListItem.set_item('Title', "My new folder!");
```